# How to implement SSL Pinning in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, http

So, I am using FHttpModule to initialize my HTTP request and set different parameters to it. Like this :

```
TSharedRef<IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> HttpRequest = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
HttpRequest->SetVerb("GET");
```

Now with this HttpRequest, I want to add SSL pinning using the public key. So when the request is going to do a handshake with the server, it should there itself validate the request.

I searched a lot but did not find anything. OpenSSL code is too hard to understand and I tried this:
`ISslCertificateManager` to bind with FHttpModule but it did not work.

Can anybody help here?